# Axios api call twise with 204 no content

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, axios, laravel-8

i'm getting error while i'm calling simple post api and it throws 422 with 204. and in my code i used try and catch. it every time going to catch. i'm using laravel as a backend and vue.js 3 as a frontend. for api calling i'm using axios.

[204 preflight error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9kv1.png)

I checked solutions in google but they all asking for sanctumn/csrf-cookie. but i'm not using sanctum in my current flow.

Comment: You problem is on laraval side. You may have entity validations on your endpoint which fails because the request payload is incorrect.

Comment: Error codes do not provide enough detail for others to give precise and definite advice.  All we can do is guess without any details regarding the request or how your backend is attempting to receive and process the request.

Comment: Make sure you have this header: `'Accept' : 'application/json'`